# No me funciona el clearInterval

Tags: javascript

Estimados buenas noches!!

Soy nuevo en Javascript y estoy tratando de limpiar un intervalo de links pero veo que a la hora de realizarlo el intervalo continua en un loop infinito, que estoy haciendo mal que no lo puedo ver??

```js
let links = ['google.com', 'youtube.com','facebook.com', 'twitter.com'];
let limite = 4;
let i = 1;
const intervalOpen = setInterval(()=>{
    links.forEach(link => {
       console.log(link);       
    });

    if (i > limite){
        clearInterval(intervalOpen);
        console.log('interval cleared!');
    }     
    
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Este es tu código. Solo le añadí un `console.log()` con la variable `i`. Si lo ejecutas y miras la salida podrás notar qué es lo que está pasando.

```js
let links = ['google.com', 'youtube.com','facebook.com', 'twitter.com']
let limite = 4
let i = 1
const intervalOpen = setInterval(()=>{
    links.forEach(link => {
       console.log(link)      
    });

    if (i >= limite){
        clearInterval(intervalOpen)
        console.log('interval cleared!')
    }
    // Añadí esta línea    
    console.log(i)
}, 1000)
```

Si no pudiste detectar el problema ahora, te lo explico.

---

Cada vez que llamas la función, el código dentro del `if` no llega a ejecutarse nunca porque `i` permanece constante.

La solución es muy simple. Solo aumenta `i`. Un ejemplo para que lo veas más claro:

```js
let i = 0
let limite = 4
const intervalOpen = setInterval(()=>{
    console.log("Repetición " + i)
    
    if (++i >= limite){
        clearInterval(intervalOpen)
        console.log('Intervalo terminado')
        return
    }
}, 1000)
```